# Silverlight updating my source objects, how to update my UI

Tags: silverlight

I have a small silverlight app, where i have a list of objects with a Name and a Description. I databind them to a listbox, and show them, no problems.

However i want to be able to change the name or the description from my codebehind (updated through a webservice) and make the UI update, how to make the ui reflect the change of e.g. my name?

**EDIT:**
Made the binding twoway, implemented the interface INotifyPropertyChanged interface, still not working. Debugging shows that the PropertyChanged event is not assigned

```
public string Name 
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        } 
    }
```

and the OnPropertyChanged method

```
private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
```

I never get into the 'if', the event is null i.e. not assigned by anyone ???

**SOLUTION:**
Updated the setter to use the instance variable of 'name', tried it first with the property 'Name' this gave a stackoverflow :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the binding mode to be `TwoWay`. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072%28VS.95%29.aspx#direction_of_the_data_flow